# Struggling to File not found at path(FileNotFoundException) in lavavel 8

Tags: laravel, upload

I'm doing a test to download the file

The script I have so far:

```
<a href="{{ route('export.download_response') }}">
    <button>Export(Response)</button>
</a>


class ExportController extends Controller
{
    public function download_response(){
        $filePath = Storage::path('public/test.png');
        $fileName = 'test.png';
        $mimeType = Storage::mimeType($filePath);
        $headers = [['Content-Type' => $mimeType]];
        return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
    }
}


Route::get('/export/download_response', [ExportController::class, 'download_response'])->name('export.download_response');
```

I have already put the file test.png in the path storage/app/public/test.png

But there are still error messages:
FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: var/www/html/lav_8_filedownload/storage/app/public/test.png

[full code](https://github.com/YukoLeong/lav_8_filedownload)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `Storage::path()` function is file is not exist. so you need to add check before `Storage::exists()`

```php
<a href="{{ route('export.download_response') }}">
    <button>Export(Response)</button>
</a>


class ExportController extends Controller
{
    public function download_response(){
        if(Storage::exists('public/test.png')) {
          return response(['message'=> 'No File Found.']);
        }

        Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg')
        $filePath = Storage::path('public/test.png');
        $fileName = 'test.png';
        $mimeType = Storage::mimeType($filePath);
        $headers = [['Content-Type' => $mimeType]];
        return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
    }
}


Route::get('/export/download_response', [ExportController::class, 'download_response'])->name('export.download_response');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it just returns the message but still can't download the pictures inside the path correctly

Comment: @rorona yeah becouse image is not exist